# Probability that a random variable is greater than another?

Tags: probability

If $Y$ and $X$ are uniform R.V.s on $[0,1, ..., n]$ and independent, how does one calculate something like $P(X \ge Y)$?

Comment: I would say there are three possibilities.  $(X > Y)$, $(X < Y)$, or $(X = Y)$.  One seems easiest to calculate and the other two should be equal.

Answer (score 4):

There are $n+1$ numbers in $[0,1, \dots, n]$ so there is a $\frac{1}{n+1}$ probability that $X=Y$.

The probability that $X>Y$ is half of what's left $\frac{1-\frac{1}{n+1}}{2}=\frac{n}{2n+2}$

Thus $P(X\ge Y)=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{n}{2n+2}=\frac{n+2}{2n+2}$

Comment: ${}=\frac12+\frac1{2n+2}$, meaning that—for large $n$—this is almost $\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

Think of all possible outcomes as an ordered pairs and count the desirable ones.

I get $P(X\ge Y)=\frac{n+1}{2n}$.

Comment: You probably looked at set $\{1,\dots\,n\}$ in stead of set $\{0,1,\dots\,n\}$

Comment: I did. Just change $n$ everywhere to $n+1$ in my answer